# AngularJS - ngRepeat to show selected row as active

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been struggling with the `ng-repeat` to show the selected row as active.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please find Plukr for this here
http://plnkr.co/edit/PXgoCkqcKrZKPakjvlvc?p=preview

Please note that I have been successful with doing this when used on a navbar menu where in the HTML I have

```
ng-class="{'active' : setActive('/blah')}">
```

and in the controller I have

```
$scope.setActive = function (loc) {
    return loc === $location.path();
};
```

but this clearly don't work here for me.

Comment: Your plnkr does not match what you have shown here.

Comment: Hi sorry it was not clear..I tried those bits but it didnt work. So I decided to take it out of plunkr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```
ng-class="{active:item == selected}"
```

to your `<a>` items

http://plnkr.co/edit/gwhKwFkpTaA4EWJ8vrAO?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ng-class="{'active':activeItem(item)}"
```

then in your script:

```
$scope.activeItem=function(item){
    return item.$id == $scope.selected.$id
}
```

**[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ykepVtPWen1mu3MuEKCu?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, although I have not used this method, this has taught me something for something else I have to do.